# Grouping financial data in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm creating some reports for my own personal finances. I want to see amount spend per day, including days with no values. I have two tables [transactions] & [2018_dates].

-[transactions] my 2018 transactions in 2018 so far, includes a date field.
-[2018_dates] is one column, with a row denoting each day in 2018, 1/1-12/31.

I've got a relationship between the tables on the date column.

How do I group transactions by date (with total amount per date)...including days with zero transactions?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a Measure for this using + 0 to always return 0 for normally empty cells e.g.

```
Total Amount = SUM ( transactions[amount] ) + 0
```

Then in the visual you can show the date column (from your dates table) and the **Total Amount** measure - it will automatically group by date.

By default it will generate a Year / Quarter / Month / Day hierarchy, but you can customize that.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

- Created a relationship on the date columns in both tables.
- Created a table visual with date and transaction amount (summed).
- Clicked the drop down on 2018 dates and showed values with no data.